# Proving a sequence is unbounded

Tags: sequences-and-series

The sequence is $(u_{n})_{n}$ for which $u_{n}=e^{n}$ 
The answer I have says that for any given positive real $U$, the term of index/position $n=\left \lfloor \ln(n+1) \right \rfloor + 1$  will be such that $\left | u_{n} \right |> U$. 
I don't understand this answer. Can someone please explain?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hint: for any $x$, $\lfloor x\rfloor+1>x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Proving a sequence is unbounded means that you must show that for any large number $N$ there is no $M$ such that $u_M < N$ and that $u_k$ is also smaller than $N$ for every $k>M$.

For $u_k = e^k$ this can be done by showing that
$$e^k > N$$ if we pick $k = \lfloor \log (N+1)\rfloor + 1$
Because then you have
$$e^{\lfloor \log (N+1)\rfloor + 1} > N $$ since $N\le e^{\lfloor \log (N+1)\rfloor} \le N + 1$

Therefore for any bound $N$ you can show that the sequence outgrows it.

For a sequence like $\{2,-1,20,-1,200,\ldots\}$ perhaps the easiest way to show it is unbounded is to forget about the part that doesn't fit the growing pattern. That is, consider instead the sequence $\{2, 20, 200\}$ You can show that this is unbounded, and it is a subsequence of the original sequence. Any sequence with an unbounded subsequence is itself bounded.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! If I may ask one additional question: the conditions you defined to prove no bound exists made me realise that I wouldn't know if I could apply it to a sequence that would go like \left ( -1,2,-1,20,-1,200,... \right ) as for every N I would pick, even though I would be able to find M such that u_{M}> N, not all the following u_{k} terms, k being greater than M, will be bigger than N just like u_{M}, yet the sequence is unbounded! Am I missing something? Thank you again.

Comment: See my edit. Made the wording more precise.